# What to say when someone is going to sleep during day?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, salutations

Usually, before going to sleep in night, we would say "Good night" to others but what to say when we are going to sleep for an hour or two during day time? It can be in morning or afternoon or evening.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul I partially agree, but what would the sentence if the one who is going to sleep initiates the conversation? I can't say "Sleep well" and go to sleep. I can reply as "Sleep well" if some is going to sleep but not the when I go to sleep.

Comment: You'd just say "I am going to sleep/ going to take a nap etc."

Comment: "See you when I wake up" would work.